# Using values from JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an  AJAX returning JSON array from PHP.

I have the JSON array successfully returning to the AJAX request, and i am cycling through the results.

**Q.** How do i use the specific values from the array in this instance?

Currently i can alert the string of the results.

I wish to be able to use the values independently.

The array outputs in a string: `{"btn_col_preset_id":"1","btn_col_preset_title":"Pink","btn_col_preset_bg":"#ff66ef","btn_col_preset_text":"#16f3ed"}`

**The js/json**

```
for (var i in myObject) {
    if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
     //console.log(myObject[i]);
     // alert(JSON.stringify(myObject[i])); 
        val1 = ???; // this is what i am trying to achieve
    }
}
```

**Updated**

The full Ajax in which i am trying to get a single value based on key. This outputs empty alerts.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url, 
            dataType: 'json',

            beforeSend: function() {

            },
            success: function(data) {

                var myObject = data;

                // loop over each item
                for (var i in myObject) {
                    if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                       //console.log(myObject[i]);
                      // alert(JSON.stringify(myObject[i]));  
                       alert(myObject["btn_col_preset_id"]);
                    }
                }   
            }
});
```

Comment: does `console.log(data)` return a string  or an object?

Comment: Yes, it produces `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` @andrew

Comment: ok so it  sounds like you have nested obects so you could try `for (var i in myObject) {for (var j in myObject[i]) {console.log(myObject[i][j]);}}`

Comment: yes, thats managed to get me each key and value one after the other, is there no explicit way to grab a value by the key name though? @andrew

Comment: it seems you have an array of objects so `myObject` is actually an array `myObject[0].btn_col_preset_title` would get you `btn_col_preset_title` from the first object in the array

Comment: AH now that is what i was looking for, i tried writing that about 6 different ways to no joy, this is exactly what i was aiming at... `myObject[i].btn_col_preset_title` Thanks Andrew, if you add an answer i shall tick it, many thanks @andrew

Comment: ok fyi `myObject[i]['btn_col_preset_title']` would achieve the same

Answer (score 0):

Either set

```
 header('Content-type: application/json');
```

in your php which will tell the javascript to interpret the data as JSON.

Or use

```
 JSON.parse();
```

in your javascript to convert the string to an object.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to parse the JSON-encoded string then you can use it as an object in Javascript

```
var data = JSON.parse(result_of_the_request), i;
for(i in data)
{
     alert("The item '" + i + "' has a value of '" + data[i] + "'");
}
```

Note that, if you're using jQuery, there is an awesome shortcut to get the result of the resquest directly as a Javascript object. It's called `$.getJSON()`.

Comment: The data is retrieved by AJAX `dataType: 'json'` already.

The issue i have is when i try to output a single value based on the key it gives me nothing in the alert.

Comment: There are two ways of selecting a value of a JSON Object. You can either use `object.<name of the key>` where name of the key is hardcoded or `object[i]` where i is a **string** containing the index of the key. Using `object[<name of the key>]` with `<name_of_the_key>` hardcoded will result n the call of an undefined variable `<name_of_thekey>`. You will then call `object[undefined]` which will be undefined too.